# What to do when I get run time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm installing HTML e-mail template in Outlook.
I'm following these guidelines: https://www.outlook-apps.com/insert-html-to-outlook-emails/ (section How to insert clean HTML code to Outlook that has 8 steps).
I did it about a month ago with a success. The html template was able to be nicely opened in Outlook (like it is described in step 8).

Today I've deleted the one that worked and tried to installed a new one. I have no idea what I've done differently but it does not work anymore.

I get the error: run time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

The only code that I actually write in is the one that I copy paste from step 5 and then I write the following path:

C:\Users\Maja\Documents\news.html - Because this is where my html template is placed.

What I expect is that when I do step 8, a new e-mail with my html template (news.html) would open.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections Eugene. Can you help?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: This one gets yellow when I debug: If insp.IsWordMail Then  -   I'm a total beginner actually.

Comment: I think you can omit this line of code. The [IsWordMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.iswordmail) method determines whether the mail message associated with an inspector is displayed in an Outlook Inspector or in Microsoft Word. But now Outlook uses Word as an email editor everywhere.

Comment: Than you, Eugene for your time helping me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was foolish enough to not having first opened a new Outlook email and only than go to Developer tab -> Macros to select my template.

That is probably why I had this error with the email being opened in Explorer window, like Eugene has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a new email is opened in the `Explorer` window. The code listed on the page uses the [ActiveInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeinspector) property which returns the topmost Inspector object on the desktop. If there is no inspector window shown you may get the error described in your post.

Anyway, I'd suggest setting a breakpoint in VBA editor and run the code under the debugger attached.

Try to remove the condition from the code:

```
Dim insp As Inspector
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document

Set insp = ActiveInspector
Set wordDoc = insp.WordEditor
wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertFile "e:\test.html", , False, False, False
```

Comment: Sounds very complicated. But how come it had worked a month ago? Are you sure there isn't anything wrong with the path? Thanks so much for having popped in to my issue!